# Searching for older Scifi story about a captured martian creature, pyramid shaped, dangerous

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember reading an (old) Scifi story about an extraterrestrial creature. If i remember correctly, it is pyramid shaped and highly dangerous, as it has kind of a forcefield/electrical field/... around it and cannot be touched, and people around it trying to examine/study it are killed/injured. I am very unsure about that part, but i think i remember that it escapes at some point.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this story? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: I found it. "The Man From Mars" by Stanislav Lem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5):

***[The Man from Mars](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?169222)*** (1946) by Stanisław Lem.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_Mars):

> An American reporter is accidentally forced to join a secret team of scientists who got hold of a crashed spaceship from Mars with a creature they dubbed "areanthrop" (Greek: Ares=Mars + anthropos=man) in it. The areanthrop seems to be a kind of cyborg: a sentient protoplasm which in the course of natural evolution built itself a "robotic suit", rather than developing a biological body. Scientists poke, prod and pry it with all means possible in attempts to study it. Eventually the areanthrop gives them a telepathic trip to Mars and seizes control over a member of the team, and after that it is completely destroyed.

Comment: Can you expand on why this matches?

Comment: LogicDictates did already. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a Dalek: "sentient protoplasm which in the course of natural evolution built itself a "robotic suit""